# R taskscheduleR not executing script

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, r-taskscheduler

I'm trying to run a script once every minute using `taskscheduleR` library. I'm following the examples from the GitHub page but am running into the following problems:

1. R says task created but the script does not execute properly (it should write data to a file in append mode - the file in question already exists)
2. I do not see any log files - I believe they should be stored in the same location as the script being executed
3. Deleting the task using `taskscheduler_delete("rds_task")` does not work

Here's my code:

```
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "rds_task", 
                     rscript = "./Testing_Scheduler/testing_scheduler.R",
                     schedule = "MINUTE", 
                     starttime = format(Sys.time() + 30, "%H:%M"), 
                     startdate = format(Sys.time(), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                     modifier = 1)
```

And the contents of `testing_scheduler.R`:

```
dat <- mtcars
data.table::fwrite(dat[1, ], "./Testing_Scheduler/testfile.txt", append = T)
```

To delete the task, I used:

```
taskscheduler_delete("rds_task")
```

which was unsuccessful. I ended up using the Windows Task Scheduler (my computer is in French - can't change that, sorry):

[image: Deleting task in Windows Task Scheduler]

Same result with the R add-in except that I seem to be able to delete the task that way. I have admin rights on my computer (so it should not be an access-related problem).

Comment: You need to give the full path in the argument rscript. Not a relative path. On the taskscheduler_delete, that pretty much looks like not having the rights on your computer to do this. Ask you admin why you can not delete a task with schtasks.exe

Comment: Thanks for your input - I will try putting in the complete path and see if that works - I think I tried that before but I'm not sure. My current workaround is to create a .bat file that runs R using CMD. I have admin rights and am able to delete the task using windows task scheduler. Infact, I can delete tasks from within MATLAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution around this issue - wich works exactly as expected is to use Windows .bat file to run the script and schedule it using windows scheduler.

The .bat file contains the commands to run R.exe using commamnd prompt (cmd) and execute the specified R code:

```
@echo on
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.2\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH C:\Users\gma\Desktop\R_Task\script1.R
```

Above are all the contents of a .bat file. The first string (in quotes) is the location where R is installed on the sytem. 'CMD' and 'BATCH' tell windows to execute it using command prompt in batch processing mode. The next string is the location of the script that you want to execute using R - provide the full file path here.

Copy this to any text editor program and when saving, specify '.bat' as the extension.

You can create a "basic task" in windows task scheduler that executes a program/script at required intervals or based on other triggers. The script to execute would be the .bat file that was created above. There's tons of video tutorials(like this one on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLacxP97MCA)) on how to create such tasks so I won't go into detail here.