# Running script using a batch file not working

Tags: r, batch-file, rstudio, dropbox, working-directory

I am trying to create a scheduled task that will run an R script that uploads a datafile to dropbox. I read that batch files are useful for this and are easy to use with the Windows Task Scheduler, so I made a batch file following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776695/21620326). When I run the script in Rstudio it works as expected and the file appears in my dropbox, but when I run the batch file (just by double clicking it, not in the task scheduler yet), a command window opens with the text of the batch file, closes, but the file does not update in Dropbox

Here is the code I am running in R. I suspect that the reason it isn't working may have something to do with the file paths specified in the Rscript, as I don't know what the Rscript.exe recognizes as the working directory.

```
library(rdrop2)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)

#Set up refreshable access token, can pass this to any 'drop' function in 'dtoken' argument
.dstate <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())

drop_auth_RT <- function (new_user = FALSE, key = "placeholder", secret = "placeholder", cache = TRUE, rdstoken = NA) 
{
  if (new_user == FALSE & !is.na(rdstoken)) {
    if (file.exists(rdstoken)) {
      .dstate$token <- readRDS(rdstoken)
    }
    else {
      stop("token file not found")
    }
  }
  else {
    if (new_user && file.exists(".httr-oauth")) {
      message("Removing old credentials...")
      file.remove(".httr-oauth")
    }
    dropbox <- httr::oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?token_access_type=offline",
                                    access = "https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/token")
    # added "?token_access_type=offline" to the "authorize" parameter so that it can return an access token as well as a refresh token
    dropbox_app <- httr::oauth_app("dropbox", key, secret)
    dropbox_token <- httr::oauth2.0_token(dropbox, dropbox_app, 
                                          cache = cache)
    if (!inherits(dropbox_token, "Token2.0")) {
      stop("something went wrong, try again")
    }
    .dstate$token <- dropbox_token
  }
}

refreshable_token <- drop_auth_RT()

#upload file
drop_upload(file = "../Learning R/data_original/biostats.csv", path = "/auto_test",
            mode = "overwrite",
            dtoken = refreshable_token)
```

most of the code here is just creating a refreshable token to mitigate the short-lived access token with the Dropbox API, the last line is the important one (I think). My working directory in Rstudio is set to the .R file location

and here is the batch file I am trying to run:

```
@ECHO ON
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\benke\Documents\R Main Directory\Data Upload Automation\Initial_test.R"
```

EDIT: It also may have to do with the DropBox API. There is an .httr-oauth file and a .gitignore file that are created in the same directory as the script when I run the file, but I don't see why that would matter if the R script is run succesfully since it should just create those files again (?)

Comment: Where have you defined the working directory? Your .R file is using filenames only, and relative paths, but has not actually defined a root/base location from which to access them. When you run it in RStudio, it more than likely assumes a specific current directory, and by chance that works for you, but any decent code should specify the location and/or use fully qualified absolute file and directory paths.

Comment: Agree with Compo. To pinpoint where the issue is, you might try running your script interactively from Command Prompt -- if I had to guess the issue is with `rdstoken` which seems to be a file for which you either need to specify an absolute path to, or `setwd()` to read successfully.

Comment: If [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47044068) doesn't get you any further, you could define it in your batch file as a workaround. **1.** ```@CD /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\R Main Directory\Data Upload Automation"```, **2.** ```@"%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" CMD BATCH "Initial_test.R"```. Alternatively: **1.** ```@Start "" /D "%UserProfile%\Documents\R Main Directory\Data Upload Automation" /Wait "%ProgramFiles%\R\R-4.2.2\bin\Rscript.exe" CMD BATCH "Initial_test.R"```, **2.** ```@Pause```.

Comment: When defining the scheduled task, you can define the working folder. (Although I agree with above commenters - a good-written script shouldn't rely on this and define its working folder itself)

Comment: I added ```setwd("C:/Users/benke/Documents/R Main Directory/Data Upload Automation")``` to explicitly state the working directory but am still having issues with the batch file, even though it runs fine in Rstudio...